# Goroutineを使うと性能が落ちるのはなぜか

Tags: go

行列をパディングするコードをGoで書きました。
そこで下記のように並列化するものとしないものを用いてベンチマークを実行しました。しかしgoroutineを使ったほうが使わかなった方よりも時間がかかりメモリも多く使うという結果になりました。

goroutineを使ったほうが速くなると考えましたがなぜこのようなことが起こったのでしょうか。
下記に作成したコード、ベンチマークのコード、コマンド、結果を記述します。

**コード**

```
import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

// Matrix is object for matrix.
type Matrix struct {
    Rows uint
    Cols uint
    M    [][]float64
}

const (
    Zero = iota + 1
    Edge
)

// NewMatrix is constructor of Matrix.
func NewMatrix(m [][]float64) *Matrix {
    return &Matrix{
        M:    m,
        Rows: uint(len(m)),
        Cols: uint(len(m[0])),
    }
}

func (m *Matrix) edgePad(rows, cols uint, newMatrix [][]float64, w uint, y int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    col := make([]float64, m.Cols)
    for x := 0; x < int(m.Cols); x++ {
        if y < int(w) && x < int(w) {
            col[x] = m.M[0][0]
        } else if y < int(w) && x > int(w)-1 && x < int(cols+w) {
            col[x] = m.M[0][x-int(w)]
        } else if y < int(w) && x > int(cols+w)-1 {
            col[x] = m.M[0][cols-1]
        } else if y > int(w)-1 && y < int(rows+w) && x < int(w) {
            col[x] = m.M[y-int(w)][0]
        } else if y > int(w)-1 && y < int(rows+w) && x > int(cols+w)-1 {
            col[x] = m.M[y-int(w)][cols-1]
        } else if y > int(rows+w)-1 && x < int(w) {
            col[x] = m.M[rows-1][0]
        } else if y > int(rows+w)-1 && x > int(w)-1 && x < int(cols+w) {
            col[x] = m.M[rows-1][x-int(w)]
        } else if y > int(rows+w)-1 && x > int(cols+w)-1 {
            col[x] = m.M[rows-1][cols-1]
        } else {
            col[x] = m.M[y-int(w)][x-int(w)]
        }
    }
    newMatrix[y] = col
    wg.Done()
}

// Pad pads the Matrix.
func (m *Matrix) Pad(w uint, mode int) error {
    newMatrix := make([][]float64, m.Rows+w*2)
    rows, cols := m.GetSize()
    m.Cols = m.Cols + w*2
    m.Rows = m.Rows + w*2
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for y := 0; y < int(m.Rows); y++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        switch mode {
        case Zero:
            //go m.zero(...)この部分をかえました。
            m.zeroPad(rows, cols, newMatrix, w, y, &wg)
        case Edge:
            //go m.Edge(...)
            m.edgePad(rows, cols, newMatrix, w, y, &wg)
        }
    }
    wg.Wait()
    m.M = newMatrix
    return nil
}
```

**ベンチマーク**

```
func BenchmarkEdge(b *testing.B) {
    m := GetMatrix(480, 360)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        err := m.Pad(7, Edge)
        if err != nil {
            b.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
}

func GetMatrix(rows, cols int) *Matrix {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    s := make([][]float64, rows)
    for y := 0; y < rows; y++ {
        col := make([]float64, cols)
        for x := 0; x < cols; x++ {
            col[x] = rand.Float64()
        }
        s[y] = col
    }
    return NewMatrix(s)
}
```

**コマンド**

```
go test -cpu 4 -bench . -benchmem
```

**結果**

**goroutineなし**

```
BenchmarkEdge-4      100      11697971 ns/op    12066503 B/op       1198 allocs/op
```

**goroutineあり**

```
BenchmarkEdge-4      200      18919942 ns/op    33900980 B/op       1901 allocs/op
```

**実行時間**

**goroutineなし**: 1.193s
**goroutineあり**: 4.581s

**動作環境**
MBA Intel Core i7 2.2 GHz
コア数: 2
メモリ:8GB

**追記**

ちなみにzeroPadはパディ‌​‌​ング部をEdgeの値でなく0で埋めます。goroutineのコストがこの計算よりも負荷が高いのではと想像しています。もし実装を変える事でgoroutineを‌‌​​有効活用できる方法があれば知りたいです。あとgoroutineを使わなかった時の処理速度(np/op)が遅いのに、繰り返し回数は大きくなっているのはなぜなんでし‌​ょ‌​うか

Comment: このコードには、`import`文とか`Matrix`、`sync`、`Zero`、`Edge`などという定義もありますか？

Comment: もちろんありますが、重要でないため抜粋はしませんでした。

Comment: あー、そうですか。それでも、その定義なしで、自分には上記のコードを実験するのはちょっと難しくなると思いますが・・・

Comment: Matrixの定義とコンストラクタ、インポートを追記しました。よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: ベンチマークだけではなく、プロファイルも取ってみてもらえますでしょうか。
https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/pprof/ `zeroPed()` の実装が確認できないのでなんとも言えないですが、 `goroutine` の起動コストがその中での処理に対して重いのではないかと推測しています。

Comment: なるほど、やってみます。あと、今回のベンチマークではmode=Edgeしか対象としていないのでzeroPad()は関係ありません。ちなみにzeroPadはパディ‌​ング部をEdgeの値でなく0で埋めます。goroutineのコストがこの計算よりも負荷が高いのではと想像しています。もし実装を変える事でgoroutineを‌​有効活用できる方法があれば知りたいです。あとgoroutineを使わなかった時の処理速度(np/op)が遅いのに、繰り返し回数は大きくなっているのはなぜなんでしょ‌​うか

Comment: @zousan コメントではなく質問を編集して追記してください。重要なものかどうか判断しながらコメントのやりとりを追いかけるのはほとんどの人にとって苦痛です

Comment: (ymotongpoo さんの回答をコメントに変換し、回答にしかコメントされていなかった文をzousanさんのコメントに書き足しました。)

Comment: @suzukis
コメントを本文に反映させました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ベンチマークを取る場合、実行回数(`b.N`)を直接には指定できない様で、`-benchtime` オプションで調整するしかない様です。

**動作環境**

Intel Xeon E5-2640 2.6GHz
コア数: 16
メモリ: 32GB
Golang: 1.6

**goroutineあり**

```
$ go test -cpu 4 -bench . -benchmem -benchtime=100ms
testing: warning: no tests to run
BenchmarkEdge-4    100     4283143 ns/op  12070650 B/op   1210 allocs/op
PASS
ok    _/home/nemo  0.489s
```

**goroutineなし**

```
$ go test -cpu 4 -bench . -benchmem -benchtime=200ms
testing: warning: no tests to run
BenchmarkEdge-4    100     9670161 ns/op  12066484 B/op   1198 allocs/op
PASS
ok    _/home/nemo  1.101s
```

**追記**

```golang
func BenchmarkEdge(b *testing.B) {
  m := GetMatrix(480, 360)
  for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
    err := m.Pad(7, Edge)
```

`m.Pad(7, Edge)` となっていますが、

```golang
// Pad pads the Matrix.
func (m *Matrix) Pad(w uint, mode int) error {
  newMatrix := make([][]float64, m.Rows+w*2)
  rows, cols := m.GetSize()
  m.Cols = m.Cols + w*2
  m.Rows = m.Rows + w*2
```

1 ループ毎に行列のサイズが増大していくのですね(`+14`)…。なので、ベンチマークにおける実行回数が増えると実行時間が線形時間(`O(n)`)以上に増大していくことになります。

そこで、`err := m.Pad(7, Edge)` を `err := m.Pad(0, Edge)` としてベンチマークを実行してみました(意味のないことかも知れませんが)。

**goroutineあり**

```golang
$ go test -cpu 4 -bench . -benchmem
BenchmarkEdge-4   2000      937189 ns/op   1487671 B/op       486 allocs/op
ok    _/home/nemo  2.000s
```

**goroutineなし**

```golang
$ go test -cpu 4 -bench . -benchmem
BenchmarkEdge-4   1000     1232650 ns/op   1488394 B/op       486 allocs/op
ok    _/home/nemo  1.389s
```

Comment: すみません。サイズが大きくなっていくのは私のミスです。結果を見させて頂きました。間違っていたら指摘してください。上の例、つまり私のバグが発生しているほうはgoroutineなしのが速くて、バグを発生させないようにしたほうはgoroutineありのが速いという事でしょうか。あと、下の結果で全体の実行時間がgoroutineありのが長くなっているのはgoroutineの後始末に時間がかかるからでしょうか。

Comment: GetMatrixもループにいれれば正しいベンチマークができそうです

Comment: あと、benchtimeオプションはデフォルトで1sらしいです。http://jxck.hatenablog.com/entry/20131123/1385189088 なのでb.Nが大きければ速いということだと思います

Comment: @zousan 下の結果ですが、goroutine ありの場合は 2000 回実行、なしの場合は 1000 回実行されています。1回当たりでは 937189 ns/op < 1232650 ns/op となって goroutine ありの方が速いという事になります。

Comment: @argusだとすると、最初に私が実行したベンチマークはb.Nとns/opに矛盾があるようにみえます。

Comment: @zousan 最初のベンチマークでは一回当たりの実行時間が変動しています(回数が上がるごとに長くなって行きます)。そのため、単純な算術平均値(ns/op)には意味が無くなってしまっているのです。ですので、最初のベンチマークでは実行回数を同じ(100回)にして全体の時間を比較する必要があるという事なのです。

Comment: なるほど納得できました。ありがとうございます。